# Android Q 10 Connecting to a wifi that i know SSID and KEY for

Tags: android, wifi

I am making an application where I want the user to connect to a particular wifi on click of a button. I know the SSID and KEY for the wifi network that I want to connect to. This is what I have done so far, please can someone guide me what I am doing wrong?

```
WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
wifiConfig.SSID = String.format("\"%s\"", ssid);
wifiConfig.preSharedKey = String.format("\"%s\"", key);

WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
int netId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfig);
wifiManager.disconnect();
wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);
wifiManager.reconnect();
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry but that method doesn't work anymore.
You need to use the NetworkSpecifier, NetworkRequest and the ConnectivityManager class.

```
public void ConnectToSSID(string ssid, string pwd)
{
    var myNetwork = new NetworkSpecifier.Builder();
    myNetwork.SetSsid(ssid);
    myNetwork.SetWpa2Passphrase(pwd);

    var myRequest = new NetworkRequest.Builder();
    myRequest.AddTransportType(TransportType.WIFI);
    myRequest.SetNetworkSpecifier(myNetwork.Build());

    NetCallback callback = new NetCallBack();

    ConnectivityManager manager = context.GetSystemService(Context.ConnectivityService);
    manager.RequestNetwork(myRequest.Build(), callback);
}
```

And the NetworkCallback class, wich is similar to BroadcastReceiver class

```
public class NetCallback : NetworkCallback
{
    public override void OnAvailable(Network network)
    {
        base.OnAvailable(network);
        //Connected
    }
}
```